# JBoss 7 how to allow a single administrator user?

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly

We are a team of Admins using JBoss AS 7 and in the future WildFlly. I'd like to know if it's possible to lock the server configuration when one user is performing some changes or to allow a single login per user. We'd like to avoid conflicts if multiple changes are applied on the configuration. 
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to lock the configuration (like for example Oracle Weblogic does in production mode). If you have two administrators managing the server configuration, the last change might overwrite other changes. Consider using Role Base Access Control which is available on WildFly and JBoss EAP 6.3 so that you allow some privileges just to one SuperUser.